# Can we generate public key from ethereum public address?

Tags: ethereum, cryptojs, pki

I know how to generate ethereum public address from public key or from private key.
But i was wondering if we can generate the public key from ethereum public address?

Comment: If you have a signed message from that account it is possible. Look here
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13778/get-public-key-of-any-ethereum-account/13892#13892

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating Public Key from Ethereum Address is IMPOSSIBLE.

As you know, from Public key you can achieve Address via 40% of an array which was hashed by keccak procedure, and this is a one-way path.

So, let`s looking at this algorithm:

1- having public key (128 characters, hex format meaning 0-F)

2- keccak hash it to receive 64 characters, again hex format

3- drop first 24 characters which remains for us 40 character as address

4- you can add "0x" now to the beginning of this array.

keccak hashing is not reversible, if you want to brute force it it will take 16^64 guesses or one century if you can have access to a quantum computer which can guess 3.6*10^67 arrays per second.
This is except that 24 hex characters that you dropped, so add 40% load on top of it.
No quantum processor is invented yet!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple but only and only if a tx was sent by that address over the ethereum network.

In ethereum there exist `r, s, v` values. `v` is the message hash, `s` is signature and `r` is empirical pubKey and to understand this `r` you must have some background of ECDSA,which is obviously not part of the question.

So once you have them from raw-tx data you may recover `pubKey`, say Q, in following way (G is generator Point):

```
r = (vs^-1) x G + (rs^-1) x Q 
r - (vs^-1) x G = (rs^-1) x Q
Q = (rs^-1)^-1 x (vs^-1) x G
```

Good now you have all known on RHS and unknown at LHS, just calculate.

Suggested reading: [ECDSA Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm)